# If copying files from and to network drive location with my C# tool, it is EXTREMELY SLOW, why?

Tags: c#, file-transfer, file-copying

In my tool, I built in a feature that copies files from user specified location to another one. If I copy from and copy to network drive based location, then a single 2 kb file takes about 10 minutes to copy. It is not a network issue, as doing it without the tool is working properly.

Expectation: tool to copy files from one network location to another.

What happens: a single 1 kb file takes more than 10 minutes to copy. If I do it from local drive to network location, or vica versa, it is better.

Here is my code for copying:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fedPREVIEW.Text))
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(pathofsrcfilesTOCOPY.Text))
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(foldercreationPATH.Text))
    {  

        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            string sourcePath = @pathofsrcfilesTOCOPY.Text;
            string targetPath = foldercreationPATH.Text + "\\01_SR";
            if (!Directory.Exists(targetPath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath);
            }

            //Copy the folders from sourcepath and place into mentioned target path, 
            //Overwrite the folder if same file is exist in target path
            foreach (string srcPath in Directory.GetDirectories(sourcePath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(srcPath.Replace(sourcePath, targetPath));
            }

            //Copy the file from sourcepath and place into mentioned target path, 
            //Overwrite the file if same file is exist in target path + it also copies subfolders and files from folders.
            foreach (var srcPath in Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
            {
                System.IO.File.Copy(srcPath, srcPath.Replace(sourcePath, targetPath), true);
            }

            // Report progress.
            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: fix your indentations, please. This is barely readable

Comment: Instead of `if(A) if(B) if(C)` you can just do `if(A  && B && C)`.  That's the more accepted style.

Comment: You are doing a lot more than just copying a file here. I'd suggest either profiling or instrumenting your code to figure out which line(s) are taking most of the time.

Comment: Why are you doing this job 100 times? for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)

Answer (score 4):

You are doing the same thing 100 times here (i.e., "copying a file" by what you say this is doing, 100 times).

But you say the problem is copying one file, while the provided source shows a complete path replication (creating the directories then copying all files... 100 times!).

Just debug your code and see what it is doing... if a **single** `System.IO.File.Copy` operation for a 2kb file takes 10 minutes, then your question is right... as you are posting it, either the question is wrong, or your measurements are, since your code is doing much more than copying a file (... and it's doing it 100 times!)

... 100 times!

Comment: Thank you for your response. What it is supposed to be doing is:
- copy all folders, subfolders and files from oner folder to another.

The following part is there for copying files:
`foreach (var srcPath in Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
            {
                System.IO.File.Copy(srcPath, srcPath.Replace(sourcePath, targetPath), true);
            }`

And the other part is to copy folders and files in it.

Comment: @AndreasWard yes... 100 times! So no wonder it's taking long :-) Even if that `foreach` only included one file, your worker would be doing the same thing 100 times (due to the `for(int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)` block on which it is enclosed.

Comment: Oh, I thought that is going for the progress bar part (like having 100% as maximum value). Sorry, I am not a develeoper just a 11 years old who is experimenting... I am not saying everything is clear, though. :( Thank you for your help, I'll give it a try and see what is does in fact.

Comment: Your `for` block repeats the operation 100 times for everything that is within it, enclosed on the brackets `{ }` (that includes all the directory creating and file copying operations)

Comment: *If* you want to report progress from 1 to 100, you should be doing it in the `foreach` block that is copying the files (first counting the number of files to copy, then passing in the percentage as you iterate over them performing the actual copy operation), not repeating the whole operation 100 times just for the sake of it :-)

Comment: Thank you, @Jcl. Yes, indeed if I change the number, then it does the job (so it is definitely a performance improvement :)), but the progress bar stops at 1. I've been struggling it for more than a week now, I was glad it finally Works... and no, not really. Thank you for all your help, it really helped to get rid of the headache! :)

Comment: If are doing the copy operation via `File.Copy` there's no way you can report progress for a single file. You could report the percentage of files being copied (if there are more than one), but not report "within the copy operation". There are ways to do it, but that's way beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: **the percentage of files being copied** - actually that would do the job for me. What I want to achive is that the user would see that the progress is going, and that once the progress is done = 100%.

Comment: Then you need to store the list of files (from `Directory.GetFiles`), and have a variable increment on each `File.Copy` operation. Get the percentaje out of it (`current_file_being_copied*100/total_number_of_files`) and report that while you copy. I'll leave the code to you (since giving working code is not the spirit of stack overflow), but it's rather easy and learning it will probably help you understand better iterators and loop blocks. Good luck!

Comment: I've been trying, but somewhat my experiment made the progressbar now to show anything. :( Well, the idea I cam up with is to set progress bar's property "Maximum" to 2, and have the tool to do the operations twice, so now at least it shows if the progress is done. I may also experiment wigth Marquee, as for me it is rather important to show something is happening, and not that how the progress goes.

Comment: @AndreasWard that's way beyond both the scope of this question (which was already answered) and the spirit of Stack Overflow, which is about answering concise and reproducible programming questions. Find a programming learning site and learn about control flow structures: this is pretty basic and if I was you, I'd be willing to learn all of this before getting into background workers with progress reporting and such.